# String comparison issues

Tags: c#, string

I needed to compare two strings, if any one of them contains other in C#. If suppose we have following string patterns

```
string str1 = "Hello World Test";
string str2 = "Hello World";
string str3 = "Hello World Test Example";
string str4 = "No match";
```

so following function is required

```
Compare(str1,str2) = true;
Compare(str1,str3) = true;
Compare(str1,str4) = false;
```

I am trying following, but looking for if there is some more better alternatives available

```
if (str1.Contains(str2) || str2.Contains(str1))
```

Is there a way to make that check with a single call?

Comment: You already found the correct method but misspelled it - it's `Contains`.Contains and Compare mean different things in English and what you ask is definitely not a comparison

Comment: So what's the question? Have you tried this, did you encounter a problem?

Comment: I doubt there could be a better alternative to `str1.Contains(str2) || str2.Contains(str1)`

Comment: Oh, and please, define *"better option"*

Comment: if any one of them contains other, it should return true

Comment: @NextoliveTechnologies again, what's the question? Doesn't that expression work? Are you asking if there's a single method so you don't have to call `Contains` twice? There isn't, unless you write it

Comment: yes @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: So edit your question and ask what you actually won't. The answer is `no` though.

Comment: The only way to avoid to call `Contains` twice is checking the strings length and then, do `TheLongestString.Contains(TheShortestOne);`

Comment: If you cared about faster, not shorter, and had to execute many thousands of checks, specialized text-searching algorithms could be used (eg prefix trees) to convert each string into a tree and compare those trees for overlap. That's a lot of code though, and generating those trees is expensive, which is why this is only used when you have a lot of data and speed matters

Comment: That's why it's not enough to ask for a `best option` without explaining what you mean. What is OK for a search engine like ElasticSearch isn't good for comparing a few dozen strings in a desktop or web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for the length of the strings and always use contains in such a way that shorter string should be looked out in the longer string.You can use str1.Contains(str2).